# Width UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have an UITableViewController. My cell instead of this:

[image: The line separated the cells reaches the edge]

But I want that the cell is like this:

[image: The line does not reach the final]

In the second image, the line does not reach the edge of the screen and below the photo line does not appear.

How can I do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: you can disable the default line and you can draw a line under the image and thus you may accomplish this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cell template provided by default. For example

```
UITablebiewCellStyleSubtitle
```

Set its properties and it should work.

The other option would be to create a custom cell

Answer (score 1):

You can hide border with :

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, cell.bounds.size.width, 0.f, 0.0f);
```

and create a line under text

Comment: There are much better ways to hide separator. Why don't you just set the inset to the value you want ,e.g.  `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 60.0f, 0.f, 0.0f);`

Comment: the text does not reach the end of the cell.

Comment: You can insert a new line wherever you like